# Bisection method failing and results in infinite loop

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, bisection

I am trying to find the roots of the equation `g(x)=exp(2x)+3x-4`. I have to do this, using the bisection method in MATLAB.

- Initial interval is `(0,2)`
- Desired accuracy is `1e-8`

I have written some code in MATLAB, however, I get the wrong answer and it doesn't stop calculating, which seems like an infinite loop.

First, here's my code:

```
g = @(x) (exp(2*x)+3-4);    
xl = input('Enter the first approximation xl:');    
xu - input('Enter the first approximation xu:');    
acc = input('Enter the value of accuracy:');    
while ((g(xl)*g(xu)) > 0)    
    xl = input('Enter the value of first approximation xl:');
    xu = input ('Enter the value of first approximation xu:');    
end    
while (abs(xu-xl)>acc)    
     xm = (xl-xu)/2    
     if (g(xl)*g(xm)<0)    
        xu = xm;      
    else    
        xl = xm;    
    end    
end
```

Now MATLAB gives me: `xm = -2`, and continues forever giving me this value.

How do I get a good approximation of `xm`? I know it should be around 0.5.

Comment: Given your previous question on the secant method, it's starting to seem like we're helping you with some coursework? People will be increasingly reluctant to answer blanket "why isn't this code working" questions, especially if it seems like they're doing homework for you.

Comment: MathWorks has a guide for debugging short MATLAB programs: [Debug a MATLAB Program](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html). Do your method by hand a check that your code matches what you expect it to do for one or two steps.

Comment: @Wolfie I am asked to determine the root of the same function, using multiple methods. However, we have to do a lot of using Matlab ourselves, and I constantly keep getting errors in my Matlab codes. That's why I sought help here. I am definitely not here to make people do my "homework", but I can't really find help anywhere else. Anyway, Thanks for the editing!

Comment: That's okay, the fact you've shown nearly-working code and vaguely tried to diagnose the issue means you're still putting in enough effort that I'm happy to answer, just giving you a word of caution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your actual bisection method `while` loop, you do the following

```
xm = (xl-xu)/2
```

- Question: What is this meant to do?
- Answer: It's meant to set `xm` equal to the midpoint of `xl` and `xu`. Therefore you have a sign error, and should be doing

  ```
  xm = (xl+xu)/2; % xm is the midpoint (or mean) of xl and xu
  ```

---

You said you know the result should be 0.5, but a quick plot can verify it should be nearer 1.24, as the above correction shows (giving a result 1.2425)

[image: plot]

Edit: **This should be a red flag if you *know* what the answer should be!**
As pointed out by Lindsay, you have a typo in your `g` definition, it should be

```
g = @(x) (exp(2*x)+3*x-4); % You previously omitted the 2nd 'x', meaning g(x)=exp(2*x)-12
```

A final typo in your code, which you must have fixed or you wouldn't have got as far as the infinite loop, was the `-` in the definition of `xu` when you should be using `=`.

With all of these corrected, you get the desired result of 0.4737 ("around 0.5").

[image: plot2]